# Right intonation

Tags: intonation

What mean to play in tune? In melodic aspect it's not so difficult to respond. All played notes must to keep the same frequencies all long the interpretation.Harmonicaly the upper note in the accord or the double strings must follow the same way like a part of the melody. One exemple of perfect temperament with fixed notes used by this great guitar player is here:

Do you have an idea what K(half tone) is used in this guitare to sound so good?

Comment: Please could you develop your question? Currently it is not clear.

Comment: It seems like you're thinking of a certain instrument, or ensemble of instruments playing together. Please edit to explain more about that. This simple question treads some thin ice over a deep cultural-practical-philosophical chasm involving aesthetics, temperaments, abilities, etc. Narrowing to a particular genre might help keep it within bounds.

Comment: (And, as a spoiler: the simplest answer to such a complex question is "It can mean very different things for different times, places, performers, and audiences.")

Comment: (Also: it might be easier to answer "what counts as 'out of tune.'" Because sometimes there are aesthetic reasons to alter the tuning of certain pitches even from what is expected within the parameters of the music-culture, or to avoid exact, precise duplication within a unison, but skipping these alterations wouldn't be called "out of tune.")

Comment: Also, your English is much better than any of my secondary languages, but there might be some confusion due to a language gap. Here's a proposed rewording of what I _think_ you're asking; if I've got your meaning correctly, feel free to edit to use it: "What does it mean to play in tune? For unison melodic playing it's not so difficult to answer. All played notes must match each other's frequencies all through the performance. For supporting harmonic parts, the upper note in the chord, or anything doubling the melody, must match the melody in the same way. Do you not think so?"

Comment: (Finally: If my understanding is right, then this is only considering "vertical" tuning—the tuning of notes against others within the same instant. There's also the topic of "horizontal" tuning, comparing a note to those before or after it. Anyone who's heard a beginning violin recital can attest that even a solo monophonic performer can be "out of tune.")

Comment: Ok, in the vertical tuning the highest note must be conforme with the horizontal tuning in the used temperament. The classic TET12 can be changed to a better one where only the unisson will be perfect.

Comment: Given your video, do not assume its value of K is constant. It's very possible that the strings of the guitar are not tuned against each other with the same value of K as the frets (e.g. each individual string is 12TET, the bottom E and A strings are tuned precisely to a 4:3 ratio).

Answer (score 1):

It ain't necessarily so! It will depend on whether the melody is being played (sung) on infinitely variable pitch instruments. When they're accompanied by fixed pitch (piano, etc) then they will follow those pitches. But played (or sung) acapella, they will move slightly, and I don't mean move to a slightly different key, but sing more 'in tune' than they would with 12tet instruments to guide them. If that's what your question is about...

Comment: The right intonation don't depend of wich instrument or voice is used!

Comment: I believe it does. In 12 tet, there are many note pitches which vary slightly from other temperaments, which is what I mean in my answer. Maybe poor translation is getting in the way!